# copy specific text internet explorer to acces

Tags: ms-access, vba, copy, internet-explorer-11, ms-access-2007

I am trying to copy a value/text from a webpage using vba in access. This value is on 4 different places, each could be used

the code lines of these places are

```
document.title = document.title + ' - Verplaatsingsopdracht - Journaal: 4900446438,';</SCRIPT>

<caption  class="formcaption" ><nobr>Verplaatsingsopdracht - Journaal: 4900446438, </nobr></caption>

<td nowrap  class="forminput"  ><input type=text VALUE="4900446438" name="dsInventJournalTable_JournalId" style="border: 0" READONLY  MAXLENGTH="10"></td>

<td valign="top" class="information"><img src="resources/images/Info.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;          Journaal 4900446438 is bevestigd</td></tr><tr><td>
```

I am only interested in the journal number that i need to paste in a form textfield called txtJrnnr. Of course the journal number will change everytime so i cannot search for this number, I need to copy the place where this number is created in the html.
Hope you can help

Comment: Have you loaded the html into a string variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're reading the HTML into a variable you can use the Split function to pull out the data you want, because it seems to be consistent throughout

```
Dim strHTML     as String
Dim strData     as String
dim strJournal  as String

Dim varSplit    as Variant

Dim varJournal  as Variant

strHTML =  read from web object

' Split the HTML into segments using Journaal
varSplit = Split(strHTML, "Journaal: ")

' Get the second element
strData = varSplit(1)

' Strip and cleanup the Journal Number
varSplit = Split(strData, ",")

' Get the Journal Number
strJournal = varSplit(0)
```